# if condition to set the DataTextField for a databind

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm trying to set selectively display certain text using a databind.

the code looks like this..

```
        DataTable oDt;
        oDt = Apps.GetAll();
        if (oDt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            oDt.Columns.Add("AppName_ID", typeof(string), "App_Name + ' (' + App_ID + ')'");
            CmbApps.DataSource = oDt;
            CmbApps.DataValueField = "App_ID";
            CmbApps.DataTextField = "AppName_ID";
            CmbApps.DataBind();
        }
```

**The problem is that the first value shows up as:**  Select (0)..  so I'm trying to change the datatextfield when "App_ID" = 0 so that App_ID is NOT displayed, but is in all other values.

Comment: What's the type of `CmbApps`?

Comment: its actually a dropdownlist.. no clue why the original coder didn't use ddl as the prefix.. ughh..

Comment: In that case, you can try overriding `DataBinding` event and skip the item according to your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the syntax, but it will be close to the below.

```
DataTable dt2 = oDt.Select("(App_ID != 0)").CopyToDataTable();
```

Using `Linq-To-DataTable`

```
DataTable tblFiltered = oDt.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(row => row.Field<String>("App_ID") == "1")
          .CopyToDataTable();
```

Or you can use `DataView` and `RowFilter`

```
DataView dataView = oDt.DefaultView;
dataView.RowFilter = "App_ID <> 0";
```

**UPDATE**

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in oDt.Rows)
{   
    if(DRow["app_id"].ToString().Equals("0"))
    DRow["AppName_ID"] = "Select";
}
```

Comment: I was starting to use a rowfilter.. except I want "Select (0)" to be displayed as "Select".  I don't want to hardcode select in either.  So algorithmically.. if app_id = 0 don't show only App_name, if app_id <>0 show App_name + appID

Comment: @DJPlayer - Updated answer may help.